Designing the kinematics and Dynamics of a spherical joint as 3 revolute Joint
I am working on a project where I am trying to mimic human like motion and for that I am designing a 7 DOF arm with the spherical joint in shoulder as 3R joints and 2R  joints for elbow and 2R joint for wrist respectively. I am using DH parameters to design the 3 revolute joints at the same location. But, the 3R joints are connected to just a single link which is the shoulder in my case. I want to provide dynamic parameters like  mass, inertia and com associated with the joints and the link. I am struggling to formulate it how can I provide the parameters and model a single link with multiple DOF. Usually, most robotic models have a single link associated with each DOF.
Any help on designing the URDF or some references will be really helpful.
Here is my code for creating the shoulder 3 DOF as  3R joints using peter Corke's Robotics toolbox.
class human_7DOF_arm(DHRobot):
    """
    class that models a 4 DOF human-like anthropomorphic arm
    See Ref: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0094114X21003700

    DH Table:
    a   alpha   d   theta
    0   -pi/2   0   q1
    0    pi/2   0   q2+pi/2 (offset)
    0    -pi/2  l1  q3
    0    pi/2   0   q4
    0    -pi/2  l2  q5
    0    -pi/2  0   q6-pi/2
    0    0      0   q7

The code snippet is a part of the entire arm that only models the  shoulder joint and the link.
    """

    def __init__(self, symbolic = False):

        if symbolic:
            import spatialmath.base.symbolic as sym

            zero = sym.zero()
            pi = sym.pi()
        else:
            from math import pi
            zero = 0.0
        
        deg = pi/180
        inch = 0.0254
        base = 3.45 * inch

        # Dynamic Parameters:

        # Length of the Links:
        l1 = 0.31
        l2 = l1
        l3 = l1

        
        # Mass of the links (assumed same mass for all 3 joints):
        m1 = 1.94
        m2 = m1
        m3 = m1 

        


        # Principal Moment of Inertia for human arm segments: 
        # Ref : Investigation of inertial properties of human body

        Inertia = [[ 22e-4, 133e-4, 133e-4, 0, 0, 0],
             [133e-4 , 133e-4,  22e-4,  0, 0, 0],
             [133e-4,  22e-4, 133e-4,  0, 0, 0],

        

        # Compute The center of mass: About the Link Reference axis
        COM= [[0.15, 0.032, 0.006],
             [0.006, 0.032, 0.15],
             [-(l3-0.15), 0.006,  0.032],

 
 
        L = [
            RevoluteDH(
                d = 0,
                a = 0,
                alpha = -pi/2,
                offset = zero,
                m = mass[0],
                I = Inertia[0],
                r = COM[0],
                qlim = [0 * deg, 180 * deg], # Shoulder Adduction: Checked for limits :[0, 180]

            ),

            RevoluteDH(
                d = 0,
                a = 0,
                alpha = pi/2,
                offset = pi/2,
                m = mass[1],
                I = Inertia[1],
                r = COM[1],
                qlim = [-90* deg, 145 * deg], # Shoulder Flexion-Extension: checked for limits : [-90, 145]

            ),

            RevoluteDH(
                d = l3,
                a = 0,
                alpha = -pi/2,
                offset = zero,
                m = mass[2],
                I = Inertia[2],
                r = COM[2],
                qlim = [-90 * deg, 90 * deg], # Shoulder Internal-External Rotation: checked for limits
                
            ),



In particular, I am facing trouble to understand how mass and inertia should be assigned since a single link is connected to three joints, I  have assumed same mass for the dynamic properties of the link as you can see in the code m1= m2 = m3.  I believe that part is not correct  and there must be correct ways to model dynamics for a link associated with spherical joint.
Thanks
Anshul
